# c function to convert hexadecimal to decimal representstion

Tags: c, hex

I am using below function to convert hexadecimal to decimal but it's not printing the correct result.
Can anyone help me with this??
Thanku..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
long hextoint(char hex)
{
printf("%x\n",hex);
long hexa=0;
int byte;
for(byte=0;byte<8;byte++)
{
    if(hex & (0x0001<<byte)) 
    {
        hexa+=1*(2^byte);
    }

    else
    {       
        hexa+=(0*(2^byte));
    }
}

return hexa;
}
int  main()
{
char content[]={0x1F,0xF2,0x24};
int i;
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    long dec=hextoint(content[i]);
    printf("%ld\n",dec);
}
}
```

Comment: `^` is the bitwise XOR operator, not the "power" one. You are looking for `1 << byte`. Also, `hexa += 0 * <stuff>` is redundant.

Comment: Your initialization of content[] is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `char` value is just a numeric value stored as a binary in the computer. If you want to convert it to hex or decimal that's just a representation of the same value so the function `hextoint` doesn't really make sense and only has a meaning if you output it.

What you probably mean is to output a string which can be either in decimal or hex and for this you can use the `printf` family functions as you already did in your example code.

**update**

Reading your comment, your real issue seem to be with `float/double` and `int`, but this is independent of the representation as hex or decimal.

If you want to i.e. do some calculation like 23/100 and you want to get 0.23 as a result, then you must use `float` or `double` variables. In your example you use `char` which can only represent natural numbers between 0-255 if unsigned or -127 to 128 if signed.

Comment: what if i have to perform some operation on these hexadecimal values such as dividing it with 100.It won't work.. right??consider printf("%d\n", content[i]/100);It gives result as 0.Wat should i do now??

Comment: Your calculating alwayss with the binary values so there is no issue. YOu must differentiate between how the numbers are inside the computer, and how a user watches them when they are displayed. Hex, dec, octal, etc. are ONLY for the human user to read conveniently, but that is independent of how the computer processes it. If you have the number 128 it can be presented as 0x80, 10000000b, or whatever, but it is always the same number in the computer and a calculation is not affected by this.

Comment: Updated my answer regarding your comment.

Comment: Thanx for the explanation..I got your point but while executing following code,i am getting 0.00 as result..char content[]={0x5E,0x4F};for(i=0;i<2;i++){printf("%.2f",(content[i]/10));}

Comment: You have to make at least on of them float, in order for the result to become float. So you'd have to use  content[i]/10.0` Since both of your values are technically `int` (char gets promoted) the result will also be `int`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you have is that you are mistaking presentation of values, and storage of values. All values in a computer is stored in *binary* format. But how you present it can be done differently (hexadecimal, decimal, octal etc.).

The values in the array `content` are hexadecimal *only in the editor*. Once compiled and stored in memory, it's all binary. So you don't need any special function to convert the values, just print them in decimal:

```
printf("%u\n", content[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you do not need this function

you can print all your char array elements directely as decimal with:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    printf("%ld\n",content[i]);
}
```